# Actualización de datos que muestra un modal

Tags: java, bootstrap, java-ee

estoy queriendo presentar un modal como alerta, indicando que la persona tiene valores pendientes por cancelar, el problema es que no se me actualiza la información del campo valor contenido en el modal.
Tengo la siguiente estructura, una página principal que contiene el template, y en el form de id='dashBoardVarios', es donde inserto componentes del tipo  para ir mostrando diferentes contenidos de mi página. En una pantalla de acuerdo al valor de un campo debo presentar una alerta, indicando al usuario que tiene pendiente cancelar un pago. Mi pantalla modal a presentar es la siguiente:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf" xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:sir="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/componentesSIR"
 xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
 <composite:attribute name="beanPrincipal" />
 <composite:attribute name="idDialog" default="" />
 <composite:attribute name="textopagoMinimoArriba" default="" />
 <composite:attribute name="textopagoMinimoAbajo" default="" />
 <composite:attribute name="valorPago" default="" />
 <composite:attribute name="titulopagoMinimo" default="" />
 <composite:attribute name="subTitulopagoMinimo" default="" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
 <p:dialog widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.idDialog}" modal="true"
  responsive="true" position="center, center" showHeader="false">
  <h:form id="formPagoMinimoModal" prependId="false"
   styleClass="modal-dialog"
   style="max-width:500px;  width: auto !important; height: 75% !important;">
   <div class="dashboard-modal">
    <h1 align="center" style="color: #fff">
     #{cc.attrs.titulopagoMinimo}<br/>
    </h1>
    <div style="color: #2ee2ff">
     #{cc.attrs.textopagoMinimoArriba}
    </div>
    <h3>
     <p:inputNumber decimalPlaces="2" id="id_valor_pago_modal"
      required="true"
      requiredMessage="#{val['validacion.CampoRequerido']}"
      inputStyle="text-align: center;border: 1px solid #6a6c6d;
     height: 30px;margin-bottom: 10px;width:30%"
      readonly="true" autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="#{dif['tarjetasc.placeholderValores']}"
      value="#{ctrDiferidos.gestor.getTiposTarjetasSeleccionado().getTarjetaSeleccionada().getPagoMinimo()}"
      onkeydown="numerosPunto(event);" emptyValue="empty"
      thousandSeparator="," decimalSeparator=".">
     </p:inputNumber>
    </h3>
    <div style="color: #2ee2ff">
     #{cc.attrs.textopagoMinimoAbajo}
    </div>
   </div><br/><br/>
   <div align="center">
    <span> <p:commandButton value="#{dif['mensaje.btnIrPagoTarjeta']}"
      update="@form"
      action="#{cc.attrs.beanPrincipal.direccionarPago()}"
      ajax="true" process="@this" styleClass="aceptar"
      onstart="PF('cargandoContratoDiferidos').show();"
      onsuccess="PF('cargandoContratoDiferidos').hide();" oncomplete="PF('#{cc.attrs.idDialog}').hide()"
      style="padding-left: 20px! important; padding-right: 20px !important; background-color: #292C32;">
     </p:commandButton>
    </span> 
    <span> <p:commandButton value="#{msg['mensaje.btnSalir']}"
      update="@form"
      action="#{cc.attrs.beanPrincipal.direccionarPaginaInicio()}"
      ajax="true" process="@this" styleClass="aceptar"
      onstart="PF('cargandoContrato').show();"
      onsuccess="PF('cargandoContrato').hide();" oncomplete="PF('#{cc.attrs.idDialog}').hide()"
      style="padding-left: 20px! important; padding-right: 20px !important; color: #fff; background-color: #292C32;">
     </p:commandButton>
    </span> 
   </div><br></br>
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  </h:form>
 </p:dialog>
 <sir:cargando dialogo="cargandoContrato">
 </sir:cargando>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Para invocar a la pantalla, desde mi controlador estoy haciéndolo de esta manera:
RequestContext contextDialog = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
contextDialog.execute("PF('pagoMinimoDialog').show()");

Para lo cual, en el componente actual que se esta mostrando en el form, puse el siguiente código:

```html
<sir:pagoMinimoModal id="pagoMinimomodal"
  idDialog="pagoMinimoDialog"
  titulopagoMinimo="#{dif['tarjetasc.AlertaTitulo']}"
  textopagoMinimoArriba="#{dif['tarjetasc.textoArriba']}"
  textopagoMinimoAbajo="#{dif['tarjetasc.textoAbajo']}"
  valorPago="#{ctrDiferidos.gestor.tiposTarjetasSeleccionado.tarjetaSeleccionada.pagoMinimo}"
  beanPrincipal="#{ctrDiferidos}">
</sir:pagoMinimoModal>
```

Leí un poco acerca de como actualizar el contenido de un modal y me encontre con la siguiente solución:
RequestContext contextDialog = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
contextDialog.update("formPagoMinimoModal");

El problema es que si yo lo mando a actualizar así, no refresca el contenido del campo valor (id=id_valor_pago_modal) pero si me funcionan los botones de redirección a Pagos y a Página de Inicio. Trate mandando a actualizar el form de toda la página que como les indicaba al inicio es de id='dashBoardVarios', con el siguiente código:
RequestContext contextDialog = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
contextDialog.update("dashBoardVarios");

Con esto si me actualizo el campo valor (id=id_valor_pago_modal), pero al redireccionar por alguno de los dos botones de el modal (Pagos y a Página de Inicio) se me queda en la misma página y no se me refresca el contenido.

Su ayuda por favor, o si tienen alguna otra solución de como pudiera presentar un modal en un componente y poder actualizar el contenido del mismo.

Comment: Logré encontrar la solución a mi problema, se resolvió poniendo la siguiente línea de código en mi modal:                       <p:ajax event="open" update="#{ctrDashboard.getObtieneParent('id_valor_pago_modal')}"/>